# What do the different colors of quest titles mean?

Tags: path-of-exile

Couldn't find this in the wiki under "quests"... What do the different colored quests mean? I was assuming yellow for main story and blue for sidequest/optional, but I just got an orange one (which also seems to be optional).

[image: Screencap of different colored quests]

Answer (score 4):

There are some different colours, I'll try to summarize all of them!

**Yellow** : Storyline

**Orange** : Master's quest. They are side-quest related to certain NPC which give you access to their own mechanics. They are:

- **Einhar** : Bestiary. Catch particular monster to unlock special craft recipes.
- **Niko** : Delve. Gather sulphite for your mine cart and explore a deadly subterranean mine.
- **Jun** : Fight against an evil organization called Syndicate, found out the lieutenant while investigating for the location and identity of their leader.
- **Alva** : Travel in time to discover the position of a lost temple.
- **Zana** : End-game "main" quest. Help her save the world from heroes turned villains.

**Blue** : Generic side-quest.

**Purple** : Navali-related quest. Navali is a particular NPC which give you access to Prophecies, "visions of the future" wich will happens once you obtain them.

**Green** : Labyrinth related quest. Labyrinth is a challenging dungeon wich require you to found some semi-hidden areas in order to access. Completing the Labyrinth will grant you an Ascendacy, wich can be seen as "advanced class".